# Symbol mismatch between two boost libraries, due to [abi:cxx11]

Tags: c++, boost, shared-libraries

I have a C++ program that links to `libboost_regex.so.1.68`, I have two version of the so files in different locations:

```
/usr/local/lib/libboost_regex.so.1.68 (compiled with gcc-7)
/usr/share/miniconda3/lib/libboost_regex.so.1.68 (binaries installed by conda)
```

The second version is for running the Pythons binding of my C++ program. 
When running the python bindings, python tries to use the second `.so` file and I get the error:

```
undefined symbol : boost::re_detail_106800::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::transform_primary[abi:cxx11](char const*, char const*) const
```

I tried to get the symbols of both `.so` files by using: (`nm *.so |  c++filt`) and realized there is difference between them:

The first library has the symbol:

```
cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::transform_primary(...
```

While the second so files (the one causing problems) has:

```
cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::transform_primary[abi:cxx11](...
```

There are similar with the exception of `[abi:cxx11]`

What is `[abi:cxx11]`? Can I rebuild my `/usr/local` boost to have abi::cxx11 in their symbols to avoid the mismatch?

Comment: To bind with boost libraries you need to use the same versions as you used to compile your client code. And of course you can build the required boost version at your development engine. `[abi:cxx11]` indicates that you need a c++ compiler supporting the current c++11 standard at least.

Comment: Probably by rebuilding. There are maybe configurations to be done first? The tag [abi:cxx11] is documented [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/C_002b_002b-Attributes.html#C_002b_002b-Attributes) and [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Is the fact that every thing flows, flows too?

Comment: @Oliv Sure it does.